# see memory usage of the computer vs of memory usage of R in Rstudio?

Tags: r, memory, rstudio

I know I can check the size of an R object using `object.size`, but how do I check the total memory usage of R, the memory composition in R - in Rstudio?

I saw [this post](http://www.r-studio.com/Unformat_Help/index2.html?memory_usage.html), but didn't find a `Memory usage` button under the `Tools` menu.

I'm using Rstudio V 0.99.896 and R V 3.2.5.

Specific context:

I look at `Windows Task Manager` when working with R, and I notice the memory usage of the computer increased by ~7G when I `read.table` a ~2G data into R.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70902727/18063425

Comment: > Please Look in to this Answer
> > https://stackoverflow.com/q/70902727/18063425

Comment: To dynamically monitor RAM usage during code execution, check utils::Rprof (as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58250126/interpretation-of-memory-profiling-output-of-rprof)

Answer (score 10):

Use `gc()` The help file says

> The primary purpose of calling gc is for the report on memory usage.

My understanding is that the

- second column "Used (MB)"
- second row "VCells"

is the most important (human readable) number to check the total amount of memory that R is currently using. You can test this as follows in a fresh session:

```
gc(verbose=TRUE)
temp <- numeric(1e9)
gc(verbose=TRUE)
```

The remaining two (human readable) columns describe when automatic garbage collection is triggered and the maximum amount of memory that has been used in the current session.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `pryr::mem_used()`.

This should tell you how much RAM all the objects in a particular R session are using.

This should work in RStudio as well as base R.

Here's some more details from Hadley:

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#gc

Comment: Do you know where gc() fits into all this?

Comment: pryr::mem_used is simply: show_bytes(sum(gc()[, 1] * c(node_size(), 8)))