# Interpretation of memory profiling output of `Rprof`

Tags: r, memory-profiling

I am trying use profiling to see which part of my code is reposponsible for the maximum usage of 3GB of memory (as reported by `gc()` statistic on maximum used memory, [see here how](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58250531/684229)). I am running memory profiling like this:

```
Rprof(line.profiling = TRUE, memory.profiling = TRUE)
graf(...) # ... here I run the profiled code
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof(lines = "both", memory = "both")
```

And the output is the following:

```
$by.total
                       total.time total.pct mem.total self.time self.pct
"graf"                     299.12     99.69   50814.4      0.02     0.01
#2                         299.12     99.69   50814.4      0.00     0.00
"graf.fit.laplace"         299.06     99.67   50787.2      0.00     0.00
"doTryCatch"               103.42     34.47    4339.2      0.00     0.00
"chol"                     103.42     34.47    4339.2      0.00     0.00
"tryCatch"                 103.42     34.47    4339.2      0.00     0.00
"tryCatchList"             103.42     34.47    4339.2      0.00     0.00
"tryCatchOne"              103.42     34.47    4339.2      0.00     0.00
"chol.default"             101.62     33.87    1087.0    101.62    33.87
graf.fit.laplace.R#46       85.80     28.60    3633.2      0.00     0.00
"backsolve"                 78.82     26.27    1635.2     58.40    19.46
```

How shall I interpret `mem.total`? What is it and what is the unit of it? I tried to look at the documentation, namely `?Rprof` and `?summaryRprof`, but it seems it's not well documented :-/

**EDIT:** [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profmem/vignettes/profmem.html) they say that Rprof "probes the **total memory usage** of R at regular time intervals". But that doesn't fit to the 50GB which are way beyond what my memory is able to fit! (8GB physical + 12 GB pagefile now).

Similarly, as pointed out by R Yoda, `?summaryRprof` says that with memory = "both" it means "the change in total memory". But what is it exactly (is it a total memory or change of total memory), and how does it fit with the 50GB number?

**EDIT:** the same analysis done in `profvis` - when i hover ovew the 50812, it shows "Memory allocation (MB)", and hover over the black bar close to that vertical line "Percentage of peak memory allocation and deallocation". Not sure what that means... This is like 50 GB, which means like this may be perhaps the sum of all allocations (??) ... definitely not the peak memory usage:

[image]

Comment: It seems it's kb... https://books.google.ch/books?id=l-BxBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=rprof+units+memory&source=bl&ots=4nSX-sF-xu&sig=ACfU3U3VEb-h3oTuKvph9AUevQs6R8SN_Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMhNLKxoXlAhWB-qQKHVCCCJgQ6AEwA3oECAoQAQ

Comment: Yes, see the explanation in the book.

Comment: @Christoph interesting! `profvis` gave me the same numbers and marked as MB! This could mean that there is an error in that book! But anyway it seems that it's all allocations summed up, not the memory used at a single time. See my update.

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Tracking-memory-allocations for more details

Comment: `?summaryRprof` says: "If memory = "both" the same list but with memory consumption in **Mb** in addition to the timings.". So I would say MB is right. Help is also saying: "With memory = "both" the **change in total memory** (truncated at zero) is reported in addition to timing data"

Comment: @RYoda thanks! So, 50000 MB "change in total memory" - what does it mean, exactly? It's not quite clear to me... My system is not able to accommodate 50 GB as a total memory. See my update please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?summaryRprof` says:

> If memory = "both" the same list but with memory consumption in Mb in addition to the timings.

So `mem.total` is in MB

> With memory = "both" the change in total memory (truncated at zero) is reported [...]

You have 8 GB RAM + 12 GB swap but `mem.total` proclaims you have used 50 GB?

Because it is **the aggregated delta between two subsequent probes** (memory usage snapshots taken by `Rprof` in regular time intervals: If a probe is taken while the execution is in function f the memory usage delta to the last probe is added to the `mem.total` of f).

The **memory usage delta could be negative** but I have never seen negative `mem.total` values so I am guessing (!) only positive values are added to `mem.total`.

This would explain the 50 GB total usage you are seeing: It is not the amount of allocated memory during a single point of time but the aggregated memory delta during the complete execution time.

This also **explains the fact that `gc` only shows 3 GB as "max used (Mb)"**: The memory is allocated and freed/deallocated many times so that you do not run into memory pressure but this costs a lot of time (moving so much data in RAM invalidates all caches and is slow therefore) on top of the calculation logic the CPU applies.

This summary (IMHO) also seems to hide the fact that **the garbage collector (gc) is starting at non-deterministic points in time** to clean-up freed memory.

Since the gc starts lazy (non-deterministically) it would IMHO be unfair to attribute the negative memory deltas to a single function just probed.

**I would interpret `mem.total` as `mem.total.used.during.runtime` which would possibly be a better label for the column.**

`profvis` has a more detailed memory usage summary (as you can see in your screen shot in your question): It also aggregates the negative memory usage deltas (freed memory) but the [profvis documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/) also warns about the short-comings:

> The code panel also shows memory allocation and deallocation.
>   Interpreting this information can be a little tricky, because it does
>   not necessarily reflect memory allocated and deallcated at that line
>   of code. The sampling profiler records information about memory
>   allocations that happen between the previous sample and the current
>   one. This means that the allocation/deallocation values on that line
>   may have actually occurred in a previous line of code.

A more details answer would require more research time (I don't have)
- to look into the C and R source
- to understand (replicate) the aggregation logic of `summaryRprof` based on the data files created by `Rprof`

`Rprof` data files (`Rprof.out`) look like this:

```
:376447:6176258:30587312:152:1#2 "test" 1#1 "test2"
```

The first four numbers (separated by colons) mean (see `?summaryRprof`)
- R_SmallVallocSize: the vector memory [number of buckets] in small blocks on the R heap
- R_LargeVallocSize: the vector memory [number of buckets] in large blocks (from malloc)
- the memory in nodes on the R heap
- the number of calls to the internal function `duplicate` in the time interval (used to duplicate vectors eg. in case of copy-on-first-write semantics of function arguments)

The strings are the function call stack.

Only the first two number are relevant to calculate the current memory usage (of vectors) in MB:

```
TotalBuckets = R_SmallVallocSize + R_LargeVallocSize
mem.used = TotalBuckets * 8 Bytes / 1024 / 1024
# 50 MB in the above `Rprof` probe line:
# (376447 + 6176258) * 8 / 1024 / 1024
```

For details about the `Vcells` see `?Memory`.

BTW: I wanted to try out `summaryRProf(memory = "stats", diff = F)` to get a current memory summary but I get an error message with R3.4.4 64-bits on Ubuntu:

```
Error in tapply(seq_len(1L), list(index = c("1::#File", "\"test2\":1#1",  : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Can you reproduce this (looks like "stats" is broken)?

Comment: Thank you very much @RYoda!!! I am going to look into this deeply tomorrow!! :-)

Comment: I finally got to it. Thank you very much!! The deciphering of `Rprof.out` was very helpful, the `mem.used` is exactly what I want and corresponds exactly to the readings of maximum memory used as reported by `gc()`! Finally what I wanted. It's a shame that `summaryRprof()` and the other tools like `profvis` or Rstudio do not offer this output.