# Memory profiling in R: how to find the place of maximum memory usage?

Tags: r, memory-profiling

My code eats up to 3GB of memory at a single time. I figured it out using `gc()`:

```
gc1 <- gc(reset = TRUE)
graf(...) # the code
gc2 <- gc()
cat(sprintf("mem: %.1fMb.\n", sum(gc2[,6] - gc1[,2])))
# mem: 3151.7Mb.
```

Which I guess means that there is one single time, when 3151.7 MB are allocated at once.

My goal is to minimize the maximum memory allocated at any single time. **How do I figure out which part of my code is reposponsible for the maximum usage of those 3GB of memory?** I.e. the place where those 3GB are allocated at once.

1. I tried memory profiling with `Rprof` and `profvis`, but [both seem to show different information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58250126/684229) (which seems undocumented, see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58250126/684229)). Maybe I need to use them with different parameters (or use different tool?).
2. I've been looking at `Rprofmem`... but:

   - [in the profmem vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profmem/vignettes/profmem.html) they wrote: "with `utils::Rprofmem()` it is not possible to quantify the total memory usage at a given time because it only logs allocations and does therefore not reflect deallocations done by the garbage collector."
   - how to output the result of `Rprofmem`? This source speaks for itself: ["Summary functions for this output are still being designed"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Tracking-memory-allocations).

Comment: Since `Rprof` interrupts the execution in regular intervals and takes a call stack snapshot incl. the memory used it is not exact enough to find code line responsible for high memory consumption (allocation may have occured in-between, memory is freed by the gc at "unpredictable" times)

Comment: Have you tried using `Rprofmem` which tracks memory allocations as they occur (not interval snapshots)? See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Tracking-memory-allocations

Comment: @RYoda Yeah, I've been looking at `Rprofmem`... but 1) [in the profmem vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profmem/vignettes/profmem.html) they wrote: "with `utils::Rprofmem()` it is not possible to quantify the total memory usage at a given time because it only logs allocations and does therefore not reflect deallocations done by the garbage collector." 2) how to output the result of `Rprofmem`? This source speaks for itself: ["Summary functions for this output are still being designed"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Tracking-memory-allocations)

Comment: Good findings, R is not (yet) very supportive here for end users. IMHO `Rprofmem` is a good way of finding code lines that (repeatedly) allocate memory which causes slow program execution (in this use case the currently allocated total memory is of secondary importance). I have never tried to aggregate the output though (is there any package for that?) Deallocations are IMHO "only" important if I want to find memory leaks that the gc cannot release.

Comment: A first starting point would be enable srcrefs (set `options(keep.source = TRUE)` and `options(keep.source.pkgs = TRUE)` in your `.Rprofile`) and possible requires reinstallation of the packages (if not already installed from the the source code (`install.packages` with `type = "source"`). Then you can also profile into the used packages to identify the code lines which allocate a lot of memory (high `mem.total` reports from `summaryRprof`). If the code line calls custom C/C++/Fortran code or some exceptional internal R code `valgrind` et al will be required which is quite much work then)...

Comment: Is `graf` the function from the (discontinued) `GRaF` package (as the screen shot of your linked question showing "graf.fit.laplace.R" indicates)? https://rdrr.io/cran/GRaF/src/R/graf.fit.laplace.R

Comment: @RYoda yes :-) but it is from the latest version from the github: `install_github('goldingn/GRaF')`. And sorry I still didn't find time to look at your detailed answer, hope tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

> My code eats up to 3GB of memory at a single time.

While it looks like your code is consuming a lot of RAM at once by calling one function you can break down the memory consumption by looking into the implementation details of the function (and its sub calls) by using RStudio's built-in profiling (based on `profvis`) to see the execution time and rough memory consumption. Eg. if I use my demo code:

```
  # graf code taken from the tutorial at
  # https://rawgit.com/goldingn/intecol2013/master/tutorial/graf_workshop.html
  library(dismo)  # install.packages("dismo")
  library(GRaF)   # install_github('goldingn/GRaF')

  data(Anguilla_train)

  # loop to call the code under test several times to get better profiling results
  for (i in 1:5) {

    # keep the first n records of SegSumT, SegTSeas and Method as covariates
    covs <- Anguilla_train[, c("SegSumT", "SegTSeas", "Method")]

    # use the presence/absence status to fit a simple model
    m1 <- graf(Anguilla_train$Angaus, covs)
  }
```

Start profiling with the *Profile > Start Profiling* menu item, source the above code and stop the profiling via the above menu.

After *Profile > Stop Profiling* RStudio is showing the result as Flame Graph but what you are looking for is hidden in the *Data* tab of the profile result (I have unfolded all function calls which show heavy memory consumption):

[image]

The numbers in the `memory` column indicate the memory allocated (positive) and deallocated (negative numbers) for each called function and the values should include the sum of the whole sub call tree + the memory directly used in the function.

> My goal is to minimize the maximum memory allocated at any single time.

Why do you want to do that? Do you run out-of-memory or do you suspect that repeated memory allocation is causing long execution times?

High memory consumption (or repeated allocations/deallocations) often come together with a slow execution performance since copying memory costs time.

So look at the `Memory` or `Time` column depending on your optimization goals to find function calls with high values.

If you look into the source code of the `GRaF` package you can find a loop in the [`graf.fit.laplace`](https://github.com/goldingn/GRaF/blob/master/R/graf.fit.laplace.R) function (up to 50 "newton iterations") that calls "slow" R-internal functions like `chol`, `backsolve`, `forwardsolve` but also slow functions implemented in the package itself (like `cov.SE.d1`).

Now you can try to find faster (or less memory consuming) replacements for these functions... (sorry, I can't help here).

**PS:** `profvis` uses `Rprof` internally so the profiling data is collected by probing the current memory consumption in regular time intervals and counting it for the currently active function (call stack).

`Rprof` has limitations (mainly not an exact profiling result since the garbage collector triggers at non-deterministic times and the freed memory is attributed to the function the next probing interval break stops at and it does **not** recognize memory allocated directly from the OS via C/C++ code/libraries that bypasses R's memory management API).
Still it is the easiest and normally good enough **indication** of memory and performance problems...

For an introduction into `profvis` see: For https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/

Comment: Thank you for your effort! But I feel like you completely bypassed the actual question (which I state in bold) and you kept on expanding on showing stats and tools which I already mentioned as not what I want, as they are more like turnover rather than maximum allocated at a time. Thanks anyway. In the end I solved it running code manually line by line and looking at the maximum memory used statisctics reported by `gc()`.

Comment: Thanks for the honest feed-back! I am glad to hear you could solve the problem anyhow,. Perhaps somebody is contributing a better answer in the future to avoid that much manual work like you had to do.